# Win32 Virtual ListView: Cannot select full row

Tags: listview, winapi, virtualization, fullrowselect

Yesterday I downloaded a SDK example about `Virtual ListView`. The code run successfully but I can't figure out how to make ListView full row select (it only hightlight first column).
Here is how I modify source code to create ListView:

```
dwStyle = WS_TABSTOP |
    WS_CHILD |
    WS_VISIBLE |
    LVS_AUTOARRANGE |
    LVS_REPORT |
    LVS_OWNERDATA;

hwndListView = CreateWindowEx(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT,          // ex style
    WC_LISTVIEW,               // class name - defined in commctrl.h
    TEXT(""),                        // dummy text
    dwStyle,                   // style
    0,                         // x position
    0,                         // y position
    0,                         // width
    0,                         // height
    hwndParent,                // parent
    (HMENU)ID_LISTVIEW,        // ID
    g_hInst,                   // instance
    NULL);                     // no extra data
```

Although I followed [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.110).aspx) guide:

> LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT
>   When an item is selected, the item and all its
>   subitems are highlighted. This style is available only in conjunction
>   with the LVS_REPORT style.

but the ListView still refuse to select full row. How to get it work?
Here is the full code:
**vListVw.h**

```
/**************************************************************************
   THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
   ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
   THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

   Copyright 1999 - 2000 Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.
**************************************************************************/

#include "resource.h"

#ifndef WIN32

#define GET_WM_COMMAND_ID(wp, lp)               (wp)
#define GET_WM_COMMAND_HWND(wp, lp)             (HWND)(LOWORD(lp))
#define GET_WM_COMMAND_CMD(wp, lp)              HIWORD(lp)

#endif

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int);
BOOL InitApplication(HINSTANCE);
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
HWND CreateListView(HINSTANCE, HWND);
void ResizeListView(HWND, HWND);
BOOL InitListView(HWND);

#define ID_LISTVIEW  2000
```

**vListVw.c**

```
/**************************************************************************
   THIS CODE AND INFORMATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS" WITHOUT WARRANTY OF
   ANY KIND, EITHER EXPRESSED OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO
   THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND/OR FITNESS FOR A
   PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

   Copyright 1999 - 2000 Microsoft Corporation.  All Rights Reserved.
   **************************************************************************/

/**************************************************************************
   Include Files
   **************************************************************************/

#define STRICT

#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <commctrl.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "VListVw.h"
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
/**************************************************************************
   Local Function Prototypes
   **************************************************************************/

#define ErrorHandler() ErrorHandlerEx(__LINE__, __FILE__)
void ErrorHandlerEx(WORD, LPSTR);

LRESULT ListViewNotify(HWND, LPARAM);
void SwitchView(HWND, DWORD);
BOOL DoContextMenu(HWND, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void UpdateMenu(HWND, HMENU);
BOOL InsertListViewItems(HWND);
void PositionHeader(HWND);

/**************************************************************************
   Global Variables
   **************************************************************************/

HINSTANCE   g_hInst;
TCHAR       g_szClassName[] = TEXT("VListVwClass");

#define ITEM_COUNT   100000

/******************************************************************************

   WinMain

   ******************************************************************************/

int PASCAL WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG  msg;

    g_hInst = hInstance;

    if (!hPrevInstance)
    if (!InitApplication(hInstance))
        return FALSE;

    //required to use the common controls
    InitCommonControls();

    /* Perform initializations that apply to a specific instance */

    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
        return FALSE;

    /* Acquire and dispatch messages until a WM_QUIT uMessage is received. */

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0x00, 0x00))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}


/******************************************************************************

   InitApplication

   ******************************************************************************/

BOOL InitApplication(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    InitCommonControls();
    WNDCLASSEX  wcex;
    ATOM        aReturn;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = 0;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)MainWndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MAIN_MENU);
    wcex.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON));
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

    aReturn = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

    if (0 == aReturn)
    {
        WNDCLASS wc;

        wc.style = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)MainWndProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = hInstance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_MAINICON));
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
        wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_MAIN_MENU);
        wc.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;

        aReturn = RegisterClass(&wc);
    }

    return aReturn;
}


/******************************************************************************

   InitInstance

   ******************************************************************************/

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND     hWnd;
    TCHAR    szTitle[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");

    g_hInst = hInstance;

    LoadString(g_hInst, IDS_APPTITLE, szTitle, sizeof(szTitle) / sizeof(szTitle[0]));

    /* Create a main window for this application instance.  */
    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0,
        g_szClassName,
        szTitle,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    /* If window could not be created, return "failure" */

    if (!hWnd)
        return FALSE;

    /* Make the window visible; update its client area; and return "success" */

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;

}

/******************************************************************************

   MainWndProc

   ******************************************************************************/

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc(HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMessage,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hwndListView;

    switch (uMessage)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            // create the TreeView control
            hwndListView = CreateListView(g_hInst, hWnd);

            //initialize the TreeView control
            InitListView(hwndListView);

            break;

        case WM_NOTIFY:
            return ListViewNotify(hWnd, lParam);

        case WM_SIZE:
            ResizeListView(hwndListView, hWnd);
            break;

        case WM_INITMENUPOPUP:
            UpdateMenu(hwndListView, GetMenu(hWnd));
            break;

        case WM_CONTEXTMENU:
            if (DoContextMenu(hWnd, wParam, lParam))
                return FALSE;
            break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (GET_WM_COMMAND_ID(wParam, lParam))
            {
                case IDM_LARGE_ICONS:
                    SwitchView(hwndListView, LVS_ICON);
                    break;

                case IDM_SMALL_ICONS:
                    SwitchView(hwndListView, LVS_SMALLICON);
                    break;

                case IDM_LIST:
                    SwitchView(hwndListView, LVS_LIST);
                    break;

                case IDM_REPORT:
                    SwitchView(hwndListView, LVS_REPORT);
                    break;

                case IDM_EXIT:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;

                case IDM_ABOUT:
                    DialogBox(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUT), hWnd, AboutDlgProc);
                    break;

            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMessage, wParam, lParam);
}


/******************************************************************************

   AboutDlgProc

   ******************************************************************************/

INT_PTR CALLBACK AboutDlgProc(HWND hDlg,
    UINT uMessage,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMessage)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
            return TRUE;

        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wParam)
            {
                case IDOK:
                    EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
                    break;

                case IDCANCEL:
                    EndDialog(hDlg, IDOK);
                    break;
            }
            return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}

/******************************************************************************

   CreateListView

   ******************************************************************************/

HWND CreateListView(HINSTANCE hInstance, HWND hwndParent)
{
    DWORD       dwStyle;
    HWND        hwndListView;
    HIMAGELIST  himlSmall;
    HIMAGELIST  himlLarge;
    BOOL        bSuccess = TRUE;

    dwStyle = WS_TABSTOP |
        WS_CHILD |
        WS_VISIBLE |
        LVS_AUTOARRANGE |
        LVS_REPORT |
        LVS_OWNERDATA;

    hwndListView = CreateWindowEx(LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT,          // ex style
        WC_LISTVIEW,               // class name - defined in commctrl.h
        TEXT(""),                        // dummy text
        dwStyle,                   // style
        0,                         // x position
        0,                         // y position
        0,                         // width
        0,                         // height
        hwndParent,                // parent
        (HMENU)ID_LISTVIEW,        // ID
        g_hInst,                   // instance
        NULL);                     // no extra data

    if (!hwndListView)
        return NULL;

    ResizeListView(hwndListView, hwndParent);

    //set the image lists
    himlSmall = ImageList_Create(16, 16, ILC_COLORDDB | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);
    himlLarge = ImageList_Create(32, 32, ILC_COLORDDB | ILC_MASK, 1, 0);

    if (himlSmall && himlLarge)
    {
        HICON hIcon;

        //set up the small image list
        hIcon = LoadImage(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DISK), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);
        ImageList_AddIcon(himlSmall, hIcon);

        //set up the large image list
        hIcon = LoadIcon(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_DISK));
        ImageList_AddIcon(himlLarge, hIcon);

        ListView_SetImageList(hwndListView, himlSmall, LVSIL_SMALL);
        ListView_SetImageList(hwndListView, himlLarge, LVSIL_NORMAL);
    }

    return hwndListView;
}

/******************************************************************************

   ResizeListView

   ******************************************************************************/

void ResizeListView(HWND hwndListView, HWND hwndParent)
{
    RECT  rc;

    GetClientRect(hwndParent, &rc);

    MoveWindow(hwndListView,
        rc.left,
        rc.top,
        rc.right - rc.left,
        rc.bottom - rc.top,
        TRUE);

    //only call this if we want the LVS_NOSCROLL style
    //PositionHeader(hwndListView);
}

/******************************************************************************

   PositionHeader

   this needs to be called when the ListView is created, resized, the view is
   changed or a WM_SYSPARAMETERCHANGE message is received

   ******************************************************************************/

void PositionHeader(HWND hwndListView)
{
    HWND  hwndHeader = GetWindow(hwndListView, GW_CHILD);
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwndListView, GWL_STYLE);

    /*To ensure that the first item will be visible, create the control without
    the LVS_NOSCROLL style and then add it here*/
    dwStyle |= LVS_NOSCROLL;
    SetWindowLong(hwndListView, GWL_STYLE, dwStyle);

    //only do this if we are in report view and were able to get the header hWnd
    if (((dwStyle & LVS_TYPEMASK) == LVS_REPORT) && hwndHeader)
    {
        RECT        rc;
        HD_LAYOUT   hdLayout;
        WINDOWPOS   wpos;

        GetClientRect(hwndListView, &rc);
        hdLayout.prc = &rc;
        hdLayout.pwpos = &wpos;

        Header_Layout(hwndHeader, &hdLayout);

        SetWindowPos(hwndHeader,
            wpos.hwndInsertAfter,
            wpos.x,
            wpos.y,
            wpos.cx,
            wpos.cy,
            wpos.flags | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

        ListView_EnsureVisible(hwndListView, 0, FALSE);
    }
}

/******************************************************************************

   InitListView

   ******************************************************************************/

BOOL InitListView(HWND hwndListView)
{
    LV_COLUMN   lvColumn;
    int         i;
    TCHAR       szString[5][20] = { TEXT("Main Column"), TEXT("Column 1"), TEXT("Column 2"), TEXT("Column 3"), TEXT("Column 4") };

    //empty the list
    ListView_DeleteAllItems(hwndListView);

    //initialize the columns
    lvColumn.mask = LVCF_FMT | LVCF_WIDTH | LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM;
    lvColumn.fmt = LVCFMT_LEFT;
    lvColumn.cx = 120;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        lvColumn.pszText = szString[i];
        ListView_InsertColumn(hwndListView, i, &lvColumn);
    }

    InsertListViewItems(hwndListView);

    return TRUE;
}

/******************************************************************************

   InsertListViewItems

   ******************************************************************************/

BOOL InsertListViewItems(HWND hwndListView)
{
    //empty the list
    ListView_DeleteAllItems(hwndListView);

    //set the number of items in the list
    ListView_SetItemCount(hwndListView, ITEM_COUNT);

    return TRUE;
}

/**************************************************************************

   ListViewNotify()

   **************************************************************************/

LRESULT ListViewNotify(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPNMHDR  lpnmh = (LPNMHDR)lParam;
    HWND     hwndListView = GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_LISTVIEW);

    switch (lpnmh->code)
    {
        case LVN_GETDISPINFO:
        {
                                LV_DISPINFO *lpdi = (LV_DISPINFO *)lParam;
                                TCHAR szString[MAX_PATH];

                                if (lpdi->item.iSubItem)
                                {
                                    if (lpdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
                                    {
                                        _sntprintf_s(szString, _countof(szString), _TRUNCATE,
                                            TEXT("Item %d - Column %d"),
                                            lpdi->item.iItem + 1, lpdi->item.iSubItem);
                                        _tcsncpy_s(lpdi->item.pszText, lpdi->item.cchTextMax,
                                            szString, _TRUNCATE);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    if (lpdi->item.mask & LVIF_TEXT)
                                    {
                                        _sntprintf_s(szString, _countof(szString), _TRUNCATE,
                                            TEXT("Item %d"), lpdi->item.iItem + 1);
                                        _tcsncpy_s(lpdi->item.pszText, lpdi->item.cchTextMax,
                                            szString, _TRUNCATE);
                                    }

                                    if (lpdi->item.mask & LVIF_IMAGE)
                                    {
                                        lpdi->item.iImage = 0;
                                    }
                                }
        }
            return 0;

        case LVN_ODCACHEHINT:
        {
                                LPNMLVCACHEHINT   lpCacheHint = (LPNMLVCACHEHINT)lParam;
                                /*
                                This sample doesn't use this notification, but this is sent when the
                                ListView is about to ask for a range of items. On this notification,
                                you should load the specified items into your local cache. It is still
                                possible to get an LVN_GETDISPINFO for an item that has not been cached,
                                therefore, your application must take into account the chance of this
                                occurring.
                                */
        }
            return 0;

        case LVN_ODFINDITEM:
        {
                               LPNMLVFINDITEM lpFindItem = (LPNMLVFINDITEM)lParam;
                               /*
                               This sample doesn't use this notification, but this is sent when the
                               ListView needs a particular item. Return -1 if the item is not found.
                               */
        }
            return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}

/**************************************************************************

   ErrorHandlerEx()

   **************************************************************************/

void ErrorHandlerEx(WORD wLine, LPSTR lpszFile)
{
    LPVOID lpvMessage;
    DWORD  dwError;
    TCHAR  szBuffer[256];

    // Allow FormatMessage() to look up the error code returned by GetLastError
    dwError = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,
        NULL,
        GetLastError(),
        MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US),
        (LPTSTR)&lpvMessage,
        0,
        NULL);

    // Check to see if an error occurred calling FormatMessage()
    if (0 == dwError)
    {
        _sntprintf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _TRUNCATE,
            TEXT("An error occurred calling FormatMessage().")
            TEXT("Error Code %d"),
            GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL,
            szBuffer,
            TEXT("Generic"),
            MB_ICONSTOP | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return;
    }

    // Display the error information along with the place the error happened.
    _sntprintf_s(szBuffer, _countof(szBuffer), _TRUNCATE,
        TEXT("Generic, Line=%d, File=%s"), wLine, lpszFile);
    MessageBox(NULL, lpvMessage, szBuffer, MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
}

/**************************************************************************

   SwitchView()

   **************************************************************************/

void SwitchView(HWND hwndListView, DWORD dwView)
{
    DWORD dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwndListView, GWL_STYLE);

    SetWindowLong(hwndListView, GWL_STYLE, (dwStyle & ~LVS_TYPEMASK) | dwView);
    ResizeListView(hwndListView, GetParent(hwndListView));
}

/**************************************************************************

   DoContextMenu()

   **************************************************************************/

BOOL DoContextMenu(HWND hWnd,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND  hwndListView = (HWND)wParam;
    HMENU hMenuLoad,
        hMenu;

    if (hwndListView != GetDlgItem(hWnd, ID_LISTVIEW))
        return FALSE;

    hMenuLoad = LoadMenu(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDM_CONTEXT_MENU));
    hMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenuLoad, 0);

    UpdateMenu(hwndListView, hMenu);

    TrackPopupMenu(hMenu,
        TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
        LOWORD(lParam),
        HIWORD(lParam),
        0,
        hWnd,
        NULL);

    DestroyMenu(hMenuLoad);

    return TRUE;
}

/**************************************************************************

   UpdateMenu()

   **************************************************************************/

void UpdateMenu(HWND hwndListView, HMENU hMenu)
{
    UINT  uID = IDM_LIST;
    DWORD dwStyle;

    //uncheck all of these guys
    CheckMenuItem(hMenu, IDM_LARGE_ICONS, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED);
    CheckMenuItem(hMenu, IDM_SMALL_ICONS, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED);
    CheckMenuItem(hMenu, IDM_LIST, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED);
    CheckMenuItem(hMenu, IDM_REPORT, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_UNCHECKED);

    //check the appropriate view menu item
    dwStyle = GetWindowLong(hwndListView, GWL_STYLE);
    switch (dwStyle & LVS_TYPEMASK)
    {
        case LVS_ICON:
            uID = IDM_LARGE_ICONS;
            break;

        case LVS_SMALLICON:
            uID = IDM_SMALL_ICONS;
            break;

        case LVS_LIST:
            uID = IDM_LIST;
            break;

        case LVS_REPORT:
            uID = IDM_REPORT;
            break;
    }
    CheckMenuRadioItem(hMenu, IDM_LARGE_ICONS, IDM_REPORT, uID, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_CHECKED);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `LVS_EX_xxx` styles are [*extended listview styles*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.85).aspx), which aren't regular window styles. You can't specify them in the `CreateWindowEx` call, you have to set them after window creation using the [`LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761165(v=vs.85).aspx) message. For example,

```
SendMessage(hwndListView, LVM_SETEXTENDEDLISTVIEWSTYLE,
    LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);
```

Comment: Or a convenient macro which does the same `SendMessage` call: `ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hwndListView, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT);`.